# Kubectl connecting to Azure ACS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have deployed a cluster to Azure successfully. Now trying to set up kubectl to work with it.

Running:

```
az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=group --name=cluster
```

Results in:

```
scp: .kube/config: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/main.py", line 36, in main
    cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/application.py", line 212, in execute
    result = expanded_arg.func(params)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 377, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 626, in _execute_command
    reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 603, in _execute_command
    result = op(client, **kwargs) if client else op(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 814, in k8s_get_credentials
    _k8s_get_credentials_internal(name, acs_info, path, ssh_key_file)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 835, in _k8s_get_credentials_internal
    '.kube/config', path_candidate, key_filename=ssh_key_file)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/acs_client.py", line 64, in secure_copy
    scp.get(src, dest)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scp.py", line 198, in get
    self._recv_all()
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scp.py", line 348, in _recv_all
    raise SCPException(asunicode(msg[1:]))
SCPException: scp: .kube/config: No such file or directory
```

File `~/.kube/config` exists, and I can ssh to the master node of the cluster.

Any idea what on can be wrong with what I am doing?

UPDATE.

Tried running the command per one of the comments here:

```
az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=group --name=cluster -f /Users/me/.kube/config --debug
```

And received the following info:

```
Password for private key:
paramiko.transport : starting thread (client mode): 0x9659890L
paramiko.transport : Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.3.1
paramiko.transport : Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
paramiko.transport : Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.2p2)
paramiko.transport : kex algos:[u'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', u'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-rsa', u'rsa-sha2-512', u'rsa-sha2-256', u'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', u'ssh-ed25519'] client encrypt:[u'chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', u'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] server encrypt:[u'chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', u'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] client mac:[u'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'umac-128@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-sha1'] server mac:[u'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'umac-128@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-sha1'] client compress:[u'none', u'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:[u'none', u'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex follows?False
paramiko.transport : Kex agreed: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
paramiko.transport : HostKey agreed: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
paramiko.transport : Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
paramiko.transport : MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
paramiko.transport : Compression agreed: none
paramiko.transport : kex engine KexNistp256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
paramiko.transport : Switch to new keys ...
paramiko.transport : Trying SSH key 765f702f5fff7fe30260d53b5bbb57eb
paramiko.transport : userauth is OK
paramiko.transport : Authentication (publickey) successful!
paramiko.transport : [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
paramiko.transport : Received global request "hostkeys-00@openssh.com"
paramiko.transport : Rejecting "hostkeys-00@openssh.com" global request from server.
paramiko.transport : [chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
paramiko.transport : Secsh channel 0 opened.
paramiko.transport : [chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
paramiko.transport : [chan 0] EOF received (0)
paramiko.transport : [chan 0] EOF sent (0)
scp: .kube/config: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/main.py", line 36, in main
    cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/application.py", line 212, in execute
    result = expanded_arg.func(params)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 377, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 626, in _execute_command
    reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 603, in _execute_command
    result = op(client, **kwargs) if client else op(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 814, in k8s_get_credentials
    _k8s_get_credentials_internal(name, acs_info, path, ssh_key_file)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 835, in _k8s_get_credentials_internal
    '.kube/config', path_candidate, key_filename=ssh_key_file)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/acs_client.py", line 64, in secure_copy
    scp.get(src, dest)
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scp.py", line 198, in get
    self._recv_all()
  File "/Users/me/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scp.py", line 348, in _recv_all
    raise SCPException(asunicode(msg[1:]))
SCPException: scp: .kube/config: No such file or directory
```

Version of azure cli is 2.0.18. Would appreciate advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `--file -f` flag to specify the absolute path of the "config" file in .kube directory and you can use `--debug` to debug further.

`az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=group --name=cluster -f /.../.../.kube/config --debug`

Comment: I've tried it and updated my question. I'd appreciate it so much if you take a look!

Comment: I'm trying to get my cluster to be added to ~/.kube/config, and he get-credentials command seems to be the way, but fails for me. Also tried to do that with Python 3.6, still the same error.

Comment: as you can ssh into kubernetes master node, try copying the .kube dir from the master node to your local machine. This is not a fix (working on it ), but it could add the required certs to access the cluster using kubectl.

Comment: it doesn't seem that master node has the `.kube` directory. Is that possible?

Comment: Try downgrading az cli version `azure-cli (2.0.17)` , as 2.0.18 and 2.0.19 are having issues. Each k8s master node will definitely have ~/.kube dir, under which kubectl contexts are available. This is essentials for the master to communicate and control the cluster.

Comment: Do you know where I can get 2.0.17 version? Tried searching but couldn't find how to downgrade

Comment: try using: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-cli-acs/2.0.17 , azure-cli version 2.x.x are available as pip packages. you can also try downloading file from the release page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/releases/tag/azure-cli-acs-2.0.17.  In worst case use docker images " azuresdk/azure-cli-python:2.0.17 ". Refer install docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: Tried various versions of azure cli, however, seems like some clusters just get created and master doesn't have .kube directory. Which looks weird to me. When I create a cluster using azure cli in cloud shell - it gets created and a master node does have .kube directory. But some masters just don't have it there. Any ideas as for why it can happen?

Comment: yes, there will be .kube dir, but it is hard to find things in azure shell. it will be good if you are using your local terminal for controlling azure services (personal advice). I thought ur are using ur local terminal to all those operations. Doing the above-mentioned steps in your local will definitely help you. give it a try. Link for signing into azure using azure cli : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 0):

In my case, .kube/config file wasn't created on the master. There was an error during the attempt to create .kube/config file, which I have noticed by ssh-ing to my master node and looking into /var/log/azure directory. The error was related to my service principal password. With a new service principal, new clusters work just fine.